# Check of socket closure

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have an application which connected to some server. It can send data synchronously (send and wait answer) and receive data asynchronously. 
I made 2 threads. In the first thread in the infinity loop I send data and wait answer. In the second thread I'm cathing data from server and push they in queue.
But, if happened some errors when I send data (in the first thread) I have to close socket. And how can I check in the second thread that socket is closed?

Code in the second thread:

```
while (processing) {
  nbytes = recv(socketDesc, canFrame, sizeof(data), 0);
  if (nbytes > 0) {
    push_queue(data);
  }
  if (nbytes < 0) {
    throw "Error in read data from socket!";
  }
}
```

If I closed socket in the first thread in the second thread function `recv` does not take error. Now I use timeout, like this:

```
setsockopt(this->socketDesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv, sizeof(tv));
  setsockopt(this->socketDesc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&tv, sizeof(tv));
```

When error happens when I don't get answer from server (in the first thread) I set variable `processing` to false and after timeout expires (in function `recv`) loop is ended. Can I Check of socket closure at once in function `recv`?

Comment: How do you close the socket? Using close()? Have you tried to use shutdown() instead? shutdown() has options to discard pending read and/or write data, so could help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no timely way of determining that you have closed the socket. You need a variable shared between both threads and protected by a mutex. The first thread can set the variable if it closes the socket, and the second thread should check it before doing a `recv`.

Comment: So, I have to use SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO settings for setsockopt.to get the recv function completed and checking in the second thread to the shared variable?

Comment: No, set the shared variable when you're just about to close the socket, and check for it in the other thread before trying to `recv`. You don't need a timeout.

Comment: Hm. If don't use timeout in recv it will be working infinity even if socket is closed.

Comment: Why? You don't do a `recv` when you know the socket is closed. And you know the socket is closed because you set the shared variable before you closed it.

Comment: No, Example: an application is started. Both thread are started too. In the second thread `recv` is waiting for the incoming data from server. In the first thread I send data and don't get the answer. I close the socket but `recv` is working. in this case I have to stop `recv` in this reason I use timeout.

Comment: In that case you need the receiving thread to signal the sending thread through a shared variable as well. The sending thread shouldn't close the socket after a failure until the receiving thread has signaled that it has finished a read.

Comment: I don't understand. Server can send data at any time and I have to get it. If I will invoke `recv` only after when I sent data I can lost data from server.

Comment: And for example: At some time I have to close socket, but how can I stop the `recv` in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you ensure that you don't close the socket while the reading thread is reading.

You have 2 shared boolean variables protected by a mutex:

```
bool reading = false;
bool closed = false;
```

All accesses to these are are preceded by locking the mutex, and succeeded by unlocking it.

The writing thread:

1. Writes
2. If writing fails:

   1. Sets `closed` to true
   2. Waits for `reading` to become `false`
   3. Closes the socket

The reading thread:

1. Checks that `closed` is not `true`. If it isn't:

   1. Sets `reading` to `true`
   2. Reads
   3. Sets `reading` to `false`

Comment: I'm so sory but I still don't undarstand...If I invoke `recv` it will be working while it dont get data. Data can come even if don't send request to server. I have to permanently check to incoming data from server.

Comment: If I will be use timeout in `recv` I can check state of socket and if it's closed I finish loop or if socket is open I invoke `recv` again.